# Server solution for magento

Tags: mysql, sql-server, linux, magento, webserver

Hi we have a store with 30k products and we feel that we need to uppgrade the server to a new solution. My question , is the new configuration of servers overkill .
Heres som facts on the website :

Users / day  = 15000 - 20000

pages / day  = 40000 - 50000

The current server we have have is one dedikated

CPU type @ clock speed ........Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5630 @ 2.53GHz

physical CPU-s ...........       2

of Cores per CPU ............    4

of Virtual Cores (Threads) ..    16

L3 cache ......................    12 MB

RAM ...........................    24 GB

RAID controller model (C1) ....    Adaptec 5805Z

RAID level type  (C1LD0) ......    RAID 10

Stripe size (C1) ..............    256 KB

Write-cache size (C1) .........    512 MB

Number of disks (C1LD0) .......    4 (15kRPM SAS)

Total RAID capacity (C1LD0) ...    273 GB

We would like to have 3 servers one for mySql one for site root and one for media 
and the specs for theese servers are as following

Server 1 Webbserver: 
Processor: 1x Xeon E3-1230v2, 4-core, 3,3GHz
Memmory: 16 GB 
Controllercard: Adaptec 6405, 4-port, Raid 1 
Disk: 2 x 120 GB SSD

Server 2 Mysql Database 
Processor: 1x Xeon E3-1650, 6-core, 3,2GHz
Memmory: 32 GB 
Controllercard: Adaptec 6405, 4-port, Raid 1 
Disk: 2 x 120 GB SSD, Övrigt: Kvm över IP

Server 3 Media 
Processor: 1x Xeon E3-1230v2, 4-core, 3,3GHz
Memmory: 16 GB 
Controllercard: Adaptec 6405, 4-port, Raid 1 
Disk: 2 x 450 GB SAS, 15K.7

I would like to have your inputs on this im a little lost here and i need help to not aim way over target

BR Martin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above configuration looks perfect for high traffic website over magento along with mysql, media and RAID are essential too. Morever if you feel like you can always cut down the cost & resource handling with virtualization & cloud but I feel the configuration you have been providing is well enough for the future usage as you might need to add more products and traffic may rise more.

Thanks & Regards,
Alok Thaker